# Include source column number in addition to line number in exception stacktrace

Tags: java, exception

In code

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1 / x;

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at sample.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:16)
```

How I can get somebody like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at sample.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:16,12)[/code]
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: put `line number` instead of `string number` in you question heading

Comment: @MarounMaroun : OP wants to add column number with line number in exception stacktrace. `(MyClass.java:16,12)` line no 16 column no 12

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235687/can-we-get-linenumber-and-columnnumber-in-try-block-at-which-exception-occured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. When you print the exception it contains the `StackTraceElement`

This is the responsible method for above result

```
 public StackTraceElement(String declaringClass, String methodName,
                             String fileName, int lineNumber) {
  this.declaringClass = Objects.requireNonNull(declaringClass, "Declaring class is null");
  this.methodName     = Objects.requireNonNull(methodName, "Method name is null");
  this.fileName       = fileName;
  this.lineNumber     = lineNumber;
 }
```

Here there is no way to set column number.

Also `StackTraceElement` is a `final` class. you can't extend it and `override` either.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. If you want to get a more precised line number, use extra carriage returns like in this example :

```
yourObject.
    aMethod().
         anotherMethod().
             aLastMethod();
```